# React app failing to display list from objects. Getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am doing a React course here and the starter files keep giving me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

From this starter code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const notes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    content: 'HTML is easy',
    date: '2019-05-30T17:30:31.098Z',
    important: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    content: 'Browser can execute only Javascript',
    date: '2019-05-30T18:39:34.091Z',
    important: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    content: 'GET and POST are the most important methods of HTTP protocol',
    date: '2019-05-30T19:20:14.298Z',
    important: true
  }
]

const App = (props) => {
  const { notes } = props

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Notes</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>{notes[0].content}</li>
        <li>{notes[1].content}</li>
        <li>{notes[2].content}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App notes={notes} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Above code shows:

> Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export
>   (imported as 'App')

I tried amending by adding export default app and received:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like you are expecting `notes` that's declared outside your component to be the same as the one you are using inside, but can't tell unless you share the code where you are using `App`

Comment: Yes this code is from App. used the create react app boiler plate

Comment: How you are passing `notes` as props to `App` component?

Comment: ReactDOM.render(
  <App notes={notes} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

Comment: Is this in another file?

Comment: With this code the error is. Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').  And when I add a export default App I get the error cannot read property of underfined.

Comment: No same file. This is starter code the course has supplied.

Comment: Your code is working fine. What is the exact error? Post full error stack here.

Comment: I have updated the code and errors in the description just now. Hopefully I am clearer now.

Comment: Are you importing `App` component again here? This is your complete `App.js` file, there should not be any import / export.

Comment: https://fullstackopen.com/en/part2/rendering_a_collection_modules on this link on the rendering collections header is the starter code for this course.

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`? Can you post your folder structure?

Comment: Your code works fine  as @ravibagul91 said, you are likely importing App somewhere else.

Comment: I have solved the issue by using this code in index.js and delete App.js. Yes I am using create-react-app. I thought standard practise was to have this code in App.js file.

Comment: Hi DGB, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The code from [link](https://fullstackopen.com/en/part2/rendering_a_collection_modules) you are referring is the complete `index.js` file only.

If you want your code to be modular and want to separate out `App` component, in that case, you should do this,

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from "./App";   //import your component (imported without { }, because App component exported as default)

const notes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    content: 'HTML is easy',
    date: '2019-05-30T17:30:31.098Z',
    important: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    content: 'Browser can execute only Javascript',
    date: '2019-05-30T18:39:34.091Z',
    important: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    content: 'GET and POST are the most important methods of HTTP protocol',
    date: '2019-05-30T19:20:14.298Z',
    important: true
  }
]

//Pass the props here
render(<App notes={notes}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'

const App = (props) => {
  const { notes } = props

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Notes</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>{notes[0].content}</li>
        <li>{notes[1].content}</li>
        <li>{notes[2].content}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rjdtth)

Comment: I would improve upon this by using `.map()` instead of the multiple list items.  That way if you add to the number of items in your notes you don't have to worry about changing the code.